# WebRTC project for UWP

Tags: windows, uwp, webrtc, uwp-xaml

I wanted to use webrtc for video streaming in my UWP desktop application. I checked for nuget package for webrtc lib. I found 2 nuget packages. One is Org.Webrtc(deprecated and moving to winrtc) another is MixedReality.UWP. Not sure which packagee to use. Should I wait for WinRTC package.Please help me on this.

Comment: *"UWP desktop application"* is not a term I'm familiar with. In fact, it's not something that really makes sense. Since that leaves us with zero information on what your target platform is, we cannot help you decide which library to use.

Comment: Technology is uwp with xaml and c#, my target devices are windows 10 desktop.

Comment: @SaravanaKumar no idea why you're getting so much flak for this question, seems straight forward enough to me. A genuine answer was deleted by a mod so in case you missed it your best current option is the MixedReality.UWP package. The WinRTC package is likely to be some way off. You could also look at my sipsorcery WebRTC library but it is not as feature complete as the MixedReality package (it wraps libwebrtc so in theory has all the features Chrome has).

Comment: @bla We cannot help if we do not understand the problem. The question uses terminology that doesn't make sense. Understanding the technology is vital.